# Side by side configuration error when Sitecore 6.5 install on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, sitecore, sitecore6

I tried to install Sitecore 6.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2. But it was not success because the 
"side by side configuration error was given as an error just after clicking on the exe file.

**Error message:**

> "The application has failed to start because its side-by-side
>   configurationis incorrect. Please see the application event log or use
>   the commnad-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail."

Comment: See if this can help: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-pictures/error-the-application-has-failed-to-start-because/df019c0d-746e-42d0-ad68-465e18e3f3ef

Comment: I tried according to the help link. It is not giving a solution. It is different according to my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out this link for a better understanding of what a side-by-side configuration error is: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43681/Side-by-Side-Configuration-Incorrect

It would be helpful to see your install logs to know for sure what is going wrong, but without that, here's my best guess.

I suspect that either this is an upgrade and some of your dll's are incorrect, in which case we'd definitely need to get more info about what files are incorrect, or else some things with your .NET framework installation and it possibly got corrupted.  There is an issue with installing the 6.5 package that I think might be related... although it usually doesn't give an error.. it just rolls back the install without any errors.  I'd highly recommend to try the steps outlined here if this is a fresh install and it's failing with that error:
http://sitecoreinstall.wordpress.com/2011/10/04/6-5-installer-roll-back/